# How to input a list with multiple numbers (literally input it on the terminal)

Tags: python

I made a program for a homework problem which successfully passes the required test cases, and I passed the test, BUT I cannot actually make it work for myself. I know the code is correct as it passes the problem's test cases, but I cannot make it work for myself. I have a list to input from the user, and I made it so it is separated by spaces. I input numbers with a space in between and when I'm through with the list, I hit enter and get a traceback: invalid syntax on my input

I'm entering the list in one line, separating each number with a space, and hitting enter after entering the final number. It doesn't work

```
input_n = int(input())
print('numbers')
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

input:

```
3
126 564 656
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1
    126 564 656
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because there's too much wrong, and it's hard to tell what the actual problem is. If you're getting that error, it seems like you're actually using Python 2, so you should be using `raw_input`. You also need to get rid of the first call to `int`, and presumably not call `input` twice.

Answer (score 1):

this is something that changed between python 3 and python 2.7. In python 3, input() takes input from the user and returns it as a string. In python 2.7, input() takes input from the user... and then interprets it as a python command.

As stated above, in 2.7 use raw_input() rather than input().

(also though in general make sure that you’re testing your programs using the same version of python as your school uses, otherwise the differences between versions will make your life difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

Use raw_input to get the entire input as a string and then you can parse it and convert it to integers.

Try the below code:

```
input_n = raw_input()
print('numbers')
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input_n.split()]
print input_numbers
```

On the running program, the Ouput will be:

```
3 126 564 656 ==> This is input from user.
numbers
[3, 126, 564, 656]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely occurring because you're interpreting using Python 2, where `input()` evaluates its arguments as code. Use `raw_input()` instead.